# Possible occurrences of splitting a string by delimiter

Tags: python, string, list, split, permutation

I have a string : `str = "**Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo** "`

I am splitting the string as `str.split("_")` which gives me a list in python.

Any help in getting the output as below is appreciated.

`[ Quote, Quote_Policy, Quote_Policy_Generalparty, Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `range(len(list))` to create slices `list[:1]`, `list[:2]`, etc. and then `"_".join(...)` to concatenate every slice

```
text = "Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo "
data = text.split('_')

result = []

for x in range(len(data)):
    part = data[:x+1]
    part = "_".join(part)
    result.append(part)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input = "Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo"
tokenized = input.split("_")
combined = [
    "_".join(tokenized[:i])
    for i, token in enumerate(tokenized, 1)
]
```

The value of `combined` above will be

```
['Quote', 'Quote_Policy', 'Quote_Policy_Generalparty', 'Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `accumulate` from `itertools`, we basically give it  one more argument, which decides how to accumulate two elements

```py
from itertools import accumulate
input = "Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo"
output = [*accumulate(input.split('_'), lambda str1, str2 : '_'.join([str1,str2])),]
```

which gives :

```py
Out[11]: 
['Quote',
 'Quote_Policy',
 'Quote_Policy_Generalparty',
 'Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find the above answers too clean and satisfactory, you can also consider regular expressions:

```
>>> import regex as re  # For `overlapped` support
>>> x = "Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo"
>>> list(map(lambda s: s[::-1], re.findall('(?<=_).*$', '_' + x[::-1], overlapped=True)))
['Quote_Policy_Generalparty_NameInfo', 'Quote_Policy_Generalparty', 'Quote_Policy', 'Quote']
```